# Multiple synchronous XmlHttpRequests getting rejected/aborted

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

For a bit of fun and to learn more about JS and the new HTML5 specs, I decided to build a file uploader plugin for my own personal use.

After I select my files, I send the files to my Web Worker to be spliced into 1mb chunks and uploaded to my server individually. I opted to send them individually to benefit from individual progress callbacks and pause/resume functionality (later).

The problem I'm getting is when I select a lot of files to upload. If I only select 8, no problems. If I select 99, the server rejects/aborts after about the 20th file, although, sometimes, it could stop after 22, 31, 18 - toally random.

Firefox can get away with more than Chrome before aborting. Chrome calls them 'failed' and Firefox calls them 'aborted'. Firefox usually aborts the files after about file 40. Not only this but my test server becomes unresponsive and throws a 'the connection was reset' error - becoming responsive again less than 20-seconds later.

Because I'm using a Web Worker, I am setting my XmlHttpRequests to synchronous to allow each request to complete before starting a new one and the PHP script is on the same domain, so I'm baffled to see the requests rejected and would love to hear what is wrong with my code that's causing this to happen.

**This is the plugin part that sends to the Worker. Pretty irrelevant but who knows:**

```
var worker = new Worker('assets/js/uplift/workers/uplift-worker.js');
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
worker.postMessage({'files':filesArr});
```

**And this is uplift-worker.js:**

```
var files = [], p = true;

function upload(chunk) {
    var upliftRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    upliftRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (upliftRequest.readyState == 4 && upliftRequest.status == 200) {
            // do something
        }
    };
    upliftRequest.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    upliftRequest.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    upliftRequest.open('POST', '../php/uplift.php', false);
    upliftRequest.send(chunk);
}

function processFiles() {
    for (var j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
        var blob = files[j];
        const BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1024 * 1024; // 1mb chunk sizes.
        const SIZE = blob.size;
        var start = 0,
            end = BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
        while (start < SIZE) {
            var chunk = blob.slice(start, end);
            upload(chunk);
            start = end;
            end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
        }
        p = j == (files.length -1);
        self.postMessage(blob.name + " uploaded successfully");
    }
}

self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var data__Files = e.data.files;
    for (var j = 0; j < data__Files.length; j++) {
        files.push(data__Files[j]);
    }
    if (p) processFiles();
});
```

**BUGS FOUND:**

I managed to get this from Chrome console:

> ERROR: Line  27  in 
>   http://xxxxxxx/demos/uplift/assets/js/uplift/workers/uplift-worker.js
>   :  Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on
>   'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load
>   'http://xxxxxxx/demos/uplift/assets/js/uplift/php/uplift.php'.

Which points to the Worker script line: `upliftRequest.send(chunk);`.

Firebug didn't give me much to work with at all but this shows the aborted requests:

[image]

And this shows the header that is sent with the requests:

[image]

I initially thought it was a problem server-side, so I removed all PHP from `uplift.php` and left an empty page to simply test the upload-to-browser parts and posting the requests, but the problems continued.

**UPDATE:**

I'm beginning to think my hosting provider are limiting request rates by using Apache Mod Security rules - possibly to prevent my IP from attacking the server with brute-force. Adding to that, my uploader works fine on my localhost (MAMP).

I did a little more research on my new suspicions. If my homemade upload plugin was having troubles sending multiple files/requests to my host, then surely some of the other popular upload plugins available, that use the same technology and are posting files to the same host, would have similar complaints posted online. That yielded some good results, with many people backing up the experience I'm having. One guy uploads 'lots of images' to the same host, using Uploadify HTML5 (which also sends individual requests), and his requests get blocked too. I suppose I'd better contact them to see what the deal is with their rate-limiting.

Answer (score 0):

#### possible problem

I think this is a server-side issue, even with a plain php file.. the server will open a new thread for each request. Check it with `top` in the console.

You are uploading the chunks in a while loop, without waiting till the previous chunk upload finished..

#### suggestion

I would create an array of all chunks and do `upload(chunks)` and manage the concurrency there, `onreadystatechange` is a good place to go with the next chunk in the array..

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using `async: false` on the request, so it should be waiting for the previous chunk to finish before attempting to send another one.

Comment: Ah, I see.. but have you tried to do it the async way, and manage the next chunk in the `onreadystatechange` callback.. It would be interesting to compare the behavior